# routes: match '*path' does not catch POST /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am using this rule:

```rb
match '*path', via: :all, to: 'application#index'
```

to redirect all unknown routes to `application#index`.

However, it does not catch `POST /`, it returns the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/"
```

Is there a way to include this path without adding more rules?

Comment: This is a very bad idea in general as it will making debugging and testing much harder - plus you're not actually providing a meaningful error response code that will tell the client not to request that URI again. If you want to customize the response when a routing error occurs Rails provides a method to do that via `config.exceptions_app` which doesn't have such horrible side effects.

Comment: Thank you, @max. I am returning a 401 for every unknown route. I wanted to do the same with the `POST "/"` as it is returning a 404 and it's not even a json response.

Comment: Yes, you do that by providing an exceptions app. Which will handle when ANY request method causes a routing error the right way. This can either be a class you create from scratch or a subclass of the built in exception handlers. https://dev.to/ayushn21/custom-error-pages-in-rails-4i43

Comment: You will need to add `match '/', via: :all, #...` as well; however I agree with @max that you should not be just pushing the end user through to a functioning controller method. I use both of these "catch all" routes in all of my APIs however I redirect them to a handler. e.g. in grape I redirect as `match '/',via: :any, to: redirect{ |_params,request| "/api?original_path=#{request.url}" }` and then handle using `route :any, '*path' {error!("No route matches #{params[:original_path] || request.url}",404)}`